# Entity Framework Core 2.1.4 & Filtering Related/Navigational Properties Eagerly

Tags: entity-framework-core

I'm working on replacing NHibernate (NH) with Entity Framework Core (EFC) for a client and have run into the following brick wall replicating NH's filtered HasMany mapping.

E.g.paraphrasing from an existing NH entity map class:

```
HasMany(x => x.Children)
           .Where("ChildStatus = 1 and ChildType = 2")
           .KeyColumn("ParentId");
```

I have been able to do this using explicit loading...

```
var kids = context.Entry(parent)
                  .Collection(c =>c.Children)
                  .Query()
                  .Where(q => q.ChildStatus == 1 && q.ChildType == 2)
                  .ToList();
```

...but I want to do this eagerly with mapping in the context class (like NH is doing) so I don't have to refactor all the Get's in the repository classes. But, it doesn't appear that the current version of EFC supports this.

Am I right or is there a solution?

Comment: You are right, there is no out of the box solution. You could use global query filter, but it will affect all queries, including direct queries on `Child` db set.

Comment: Thanks Llazar. As much as I'd like an EF-only solution, I did find an ugly workaround: Create a SQL Server view for the filtered data and map the reference to THAT rather than the base table.  You'd think that an ORM could handle that.  Maybe EFC 2.2-ish?

Comment: 2.2 - no way (it's already in preview). 3.0+ (or 4.0+ if ever at all) would be a better approximation :)